# Как убрать расстояние между строк в контейнерах?

Tags: html, css

Пишу код для подвала, вроде всё хорошо, но возникает такая проблема:
[image: Проблема]
Расстояние между строк очень раздражает, как убрать не понимаю, нужна помощь.

```css
#footer{
  max-width: 100%;
  padding: 4% 5%;
  font-family: tahoma;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  min-height: 10em;
  height: 10em;
  max-height: 20em;
  background-color: #111111;
}
#div5{
  min-width: 33%;
  width: 33%;
  max-width: 33%;
  background-color: red;
  text-align: left;
  border-right: #BBB solid 0.1em;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  float: left;
}
.tekst{
  margin-top: 1em;
  color: #BBB;
  font-size: 0.4em;
}
#div6{
  min-width: 33%;
  background-color: blue;
  text-align: center;
  border-right: #BBB solid 0.1em;
  float: left;
}
#div7{
  min-width: 33%;
  background-color: green;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="footer">
    <div id="div5">
        <b>ОЛИМП</b><br>
        <font class="tekst">Осмысленный текст, который мне надо засунуть сюда. Потом его поменяю, но сейчас этот текст будет здесь.<br>
        &copy "Олимп", все права соблюдены</font>
    </div>
    <div id="div6">
        456456
    </div>
    <div id="div7">
        123123
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: попробуйте задать ```line-height``` ```#div5{ line-height: 12px;}```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

тег `font`  он считается устаревшим и от его использования рекомендуется отказаться в пользу стилей. Вот ссылка [ознакомится](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Element/font)

Если я правильно понял, то вы говорите про свойство CSS `line-height`. Ссылка [ознакомится](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/line-height)

**Пример для понимания:**

```css
.box {
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 2.5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  Пишу код для подвала, вроде всё хорошо, но возникает такая проблема. Расстояние между строк очень раздражает, как убрать не понимаю, нужна помощь.
</div>
```